# How to intercept and parse a video from Android app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, appium-android, wdio-v6

The task is to understand if a video quality really changed after changing it on Android app. API answer's interception isn't enough 'cause it can be misleading. The only way is to somehow get a video itself or part of it  then parse and compare with the previous unchanged one. I use JS and Appium for it

Comment: Please elaborate and provide more info. What is the task, where the video is stored. Not shure  what node.js is doing in the mix, is an Android app or a NodeJs system?

Comment: It's an Android app with online streaming of TV channels

Comment: Yes, still not clear. Elaborate "video quality really changed" "api is misleading", provide context.

Comment: An approximate estimator of the video quality (assuming the compression codec and framerate does not change) is the bitrate

Comment: @Newbie, I speak about 360, 720 and others. Just intercept the api answer of your request isn't sufficient to say that quality really changed 'cause it might send you wrong information. And I wanna know are there any libraries, frameworks or another tools enabling to intercept streaming video and parse it to make sure the quality changed (not just digits on your screen)